# I'd like to design a buck converter that charges the battery pack

Tags: battery-charging, buck

I'd like to charge the battery pack with buck converter.

Previously, I had experience designing a 30W buck converter. At that time, I calculated the load to connect as follows.
[image]

But this time, I want to design a buck converter whose load is a battery pack.
[image]

But the battery pack is actually a large capacitor, so isn't it equivalent as follows?[image]

Thinking like this, I don't know how to design a circuit. Is there a circuit diagram that can be used as a reference?

Comment: You can replace your “capacitor battery” with voltage source.

Comment: Does that mean it appears as a voltage source, not an equivalent resistance?

Comment: Yes, a voltage source with small series resistance representing an internal series resistance of battery.

Comment: I want to charge a commercial battery pack. Should I think of the ESR of the battery pack as the equivalent resistance of the circuit?

Comment: In case of batt. pack except batteries ESR you have to count with also mosfets Rds placed in series, possible shunt for current meas., wires.

Comment: Why not use a charger IC? It does what you need and is designed to safely handle batteries of your choise. For example, charging lithium batteries safely is no small task.

Comment: As a graduation project, I would like to make a circuit to charge the battery pack.
Do you have any reference materials?

Comment: Batteries and capacitors behave differently from each other. Both of those behaviors can be exploited for energy storage, but you can't just swap a battery for a capacitor or vice versa in any given circuit.

Comment: Oh, I am going to buy a commercial product for the battery pack. What I am going to make is to make a voltage through Buck to match the rated voltage of the battery pack and only charge it.

Comment: Look at any of the TI BQ charger chips that would work with your battery.  Understand their operation and you will have a reference.

Comment: What kind of battery pack are you going to connect to it? I can't think of a battery technology that you can safely charge with just a fixed voltage and no current limiting.

Comment: Oh, the cost is limited because it's a graduation project. I was going to buy an affordable battery pack with built-in BMS from AliExpress